# Selecting specific columns in Slick 3.x throws a type mismatch

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

In this Slick function I read from a User table and return a SessionUser object (SessionUser has fewer columns than User).

The problem is that this code does not compile, for each field in SessionUser it gives me the error `type mismatch; found : slick.lifted.Rep[String] required: String`. What's the meaning of this error and how to fix it?

```
def readByUserid (userid: String) : Option[SessionUser] = {
    val db = Database.forConfig(Constant.dbBank)
    try {
      val users = TableQuery[UserDB]
      val action = users.filter(_.userid === userid)
            .map(u => SessionUser(u.userid, u.firstName, u.lastName)).result

      val future = db.run(action)
      val result = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
      result
    } 
     finally db.close
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add the table definition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `map` operation in a wrong place: mapping over a `Query` object is an equivalent of the `SELECT` statement in SQL. You should place your `map` operation right after the `result` invocation:

```
val action = users.filter(_.userid === userid).result.map(_.headOption.map(u => SessionUser(u.userid, u.firstName, u.lastName)))
```

Since we are using only three columns from `users` table, we could express that by using `map` operation on a `Query` object. This way the underlying SQL statement will select only the columns we need:

```
val action = users.filter(_.userid === userid).map(u => (u.userid, u.firstName, u.lastName)).result.map(_.headOption.map { 
  case (userid, firstName, lastName) => SessionUser(userid, firstName, lastName)
})
```

Comment: I'm getting now `value userid is not a member of Seq[user.manage.UserDB#TableElementType]`

Comment: `u` is a sequence, so I tried using `u(0).userid` insteadand it works, however would this crash if the select returns zero columns?

Comment: I tried using `u(0).userid` and when the select returns no records, I get an exception `IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`, any ideas?

Comment: I have fixed my answer. You should get the head of the sequence as an `Option`. If the user was found you'll get `Some(User)` (which will be mapped to `SessionUser` then)  and if the user wasn't found you'll get `None`.

Comment: This works, however I printed the SQL statement and the application selects all the columns, not only the ones in the action.

Comment: Could you show how did you print that SQL statement and how does it look like?

Comment: I printed the statemend logging Slick: `[debug] s.j.J.statement - Preparing statement: select `is_admin`, `email`, `notes`, `sk`, `suspended`, `pwd`, `last_upd_user`, `version`, `userid`, `group_sk`, `last_name`, `last_upd_ts`, `first_name` from `users` where `userid` = 'user1'`

Comment: You could add additional mapping that would select only the columns you require for `SessionUser`. I have updated my answer.